# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create') with create in sequelize expressjs nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

Here is my code snippet

##### Folder Scafolding

```
backendstuff (the express app)
- models/currentweather.js
- models/sequelize.js
- routes/weather.js
app.js
```

##### models/currentweather.js

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  
  const CurrentWeather = sequelize.define("CurrentWeather", {
        // Model attributes are defined here
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        region: DataTypes.STRING,
        country: DataTypes.STRING,
        lat: DataTypes.FLOAT,
        lon: DataTypes.FLOAT,
        tz_id : DataTypes.STRING    
  });

  return CurrentWeather;

}
```

##### models/sequelize.js

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const CWeatherModel = require('./currentweather');
const FWeatherModel = require('./forecastweather');

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
   'climate_db',
   'uname',
   'password',
    {
      host: 'localhost',
      dialect: 'mysql'
    }
);

const CWeather = CWeatherModel(sequelize, Sequelize)
const FWeather = FWeatherModel(sequelize, Sequelize)

sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
   console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
}).catch((error) => {
   console.error('Unable to connect to the database: ', error);
});

// sequelize.sync()
//   .then(() => {
//     console.log(`Database & tables created!`)
//   })


module.exports = {
   CWeather,
   FWeather
}
```

##### routes/weather.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const axios = require('axios');

const { CurrentWeather } = require('../models/currentweather');
const { ForecastWeather } = require('../models/forecastweather');

// Added as per recommendation
const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');



require('dotenv').config();

var request=require('request');

var apiconf = require('../apiconfig.json');

var apikey = process.env.APIKEY,
    apiBaseurl = 'http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/';

router.get('/current', function(req, res, next){

    // API Returns the json - working!!
    apiurl = 'https://someapiurl.com?weather';


    axios.get(apiurl)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);

        // Storing the Response in location piece from the huge response

// Throws this error now:
// TypeError: CurrentWeather is not a function 
        const cweather =  CurrentWeather(Sequelize, DataTypes).create({ 
            name: location.name,
            region: location.region,
            country: location.country,
            lat: location.lat,
            lon: location.lon,
            tz_id: location.tz_id
        });
        cweather.save();

        return res.json(response.data);
    })
})
```

Looks like everything is OKAY, but I get this error, what is that I am missing ?

```
const cweather =  CurrentWeather.create({ 
                                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')
```

Comment: What does the folder structure look like? Might another `../` or so be needed in the path, when requiring it in weather.js?

Answer (score 0):

`currentweather.js` exports a function which *returns* an instance of Sequelize's `CurrentWeather`, while you're trying to act as if the function itself is a creation of Sequelize.

You forgot to pass `sequelize` and `DataTypes` to the function. Your `weather.js` code should look something like this instead:

```js
const cweather =  CurrentWeather(sequelizeInstance, yourDataTypes).create({ 
  name: location.name,
  region: location.region,
  country: location.country,
  lat: location.lat,
  lon: location.lon,
  tz_id: location.tz_id
});
```